# Magento recurring profiles - billing frequency

Tags: recurring

I'm a little bit confused with descriptions in Magento Wiki: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

Billing Frequency – (required) Specify how often within the billing period unit the payment system will initiate a payment transaction for the recurring profile.

So, if I have billing period = 1 week and billing frequency = 5, then the payment will be charged 5 times in a week? Or it will be charged 5 weeks 1 time a week? If the last way, then what is the reason for billing cycles usage?

Finally, try to explain me, how often such example will work:

```
Billing Period Unit = 1 week
Billing Frequency = 5
Maximum Billing Cycles = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Billing Period Unit = 1 week
Billing Frequency = 5
Maximum Billing Cycles = 4
```

This means: Charge every 5 weeks up to a maximum of 4 times (i.e. stop charging after 20 weeks).

Comment: So, in my example 4 payments will be done, right?

Comment: @magalter that's correct